# How can I filter the Object with an Array values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for bad english :/

Hello friends, I have such an Object. I load certain values ​​into a series via a button. I need to filter this object with elements of this array. How can I do that?

Each element in the array should query wtype_id. If not, it should never show on the screen.

Meanwhile, this object holds the CITY - DISTRICT - SERVICE - LOCATION system. I have to question the Service. In addition, there is a status of being more than one City and District within a Get.

This my Array:

```
0: "1"
1: "2"
2: "3"
3: "4"
4: "5"
5: "6"
6: "7"
```

This my Object

```
{
    "41": {
        "citys_id": "41",
        "citys_name": "Kocaeli",
        "sub_citys": {
            "505": {
                "subcity_id": "505",
                "subcity_name": "İzmit",
                "subcity_city_id": "41",
                "wtype": {
                    "1": {
                        "wtype_id": "1",
                        "wtype_name": "Yemek",
                        "wtype_icon": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-lollipop/32/Phone-icon.png",
                        "locations": [
                            {
                                "loc_id": "13",
                                "loc_type": "1",
                                "loc_name": "With Beyond Bilişim",
                                "loc_number": "05322510292",
                                "loc_pazartesi": "1",
                                "loc_sali": "1",
                                "loc_carsamba": "1",
                                "loc_persembe": "1",
                                "loc_cuma": "1",
                                "loc_cumartesi": "0",
                                "loc_pazar": "1",
                                "loc_open": "1100",
                                "loc_close": "1400",
                                "loc_city": "41",
                                "loc_subcity": "505",
                                "loc_adress": "Çukurbağ Mahallesi, Molla Raşit Sokak, Numara: 14",
                                "loc_tarif": "Oradan çıkınca sola doğru dönüp devam edeceğiz",
                                "loc_lat": "41.0710419",
                                "loc_lng": "29.0127192"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "wtype_id": "3",
                        "wtype_name": "Eczane",
                        "wtype_icon": "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
                        "locations": [
                            {
                                "loc_id": "14",
                                "loc_type": "3",
                                "loc_name": "a",
                                "loc_number": "b",
                                "loc_pazartesi": "0",
                                "loc_sali": "0",
                                "loc_carsamba": "0",
                                "loc_persembe": "0",
                                "loc_cuma": "1",
                                "loc_cumartesi": "0",
                                "loc_pazar": "0",
                                "loc_open": "800",
                                "loc_close": "1200",
                                "loc_city": "41",
                                "loc_subcity": "505",
                                "loc_adress": "asd",
                                "loc_tarif": "asda",
                                "loc_lat": "40.5880381636505",
                                "loc_lng": "30.481870596093742"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Function..

```
 $.each(props, function(key, value) {
            $.each(value.sub_citys, function(key2, value2) {
                $.each(value2.wtype, function(key3, value3) {
                    $.each(value3.locations, function(key4, value4) {
                        var Location = {
                            coords: {
                                lat: parseFloat(value4.loc_lat),
                                lng: parseFloat(value4.loc_lng)
                            },
                            iconImage: value3.wtype_icon,
                            content: '<div style="text-align:center;"><h5>' + value4.loc_name + '</h5><a>' + value4.loc_adress + '</a><br/><small>' + value4.loc_tarif + '</small><hr/>' +
```

Comment: Could you describe the function signature? That is, what arguments do you pass into a function and what do you expect to receive? My interpretation is that the array and object is passed in and the return value is an Array of objects which is constructed from the values of the sub-objects of `wtype` where the key was represented in the array argument.

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki I'm edited this text

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki i props = response.

Comment: I can see, where „my Object” plays in here (that is, it's `props`). But whatabout „my Array”?

Comment: I'm getting the array from somewhere else, I have to fetch wtype_id's that are synced according to the numbers (ID) of the Array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's try it with an interactive code snippet:

```js
var props = {
  "41": {
    "citys_id": "41",
    "citys_name": "Kocaeli",
    "sub_citys": {
      "505": {
        "subcity_id": "505",
        "subcity_name": "İzmit",
        "subcity_city_id": "41",
        "wtype": {
          "1": {
            "wtype_id": "1",
            "wtype_name": "Yemek",
            "wtype_icon": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dtafalonso/android-lollipop/32/Phone-icon.png",
            "locations": [{
              "loc_id": "13",
              "loc_type": "1",
              "loc_name": "With Beyond Bilişim",
              "loc_number": "05322510292",
              "loc_pazartesi": "1",
              "loc_sali": "1",
              "loc_carsamba": "1",
              "loc_persembe": "1",
              "loc_cuma": "1",
              "loc_cumartesi": "0",
              "loc_pazar": "1",
              "loc_open": "1100",
              "loc_close": "1400",
              "loc_city": "41",
              "loc_subcity": "505",
              "loc_adress": "Çukurbağ Mahallesi, Molla Raşit Sokak, Numara: 14",
              "loc_tarif": "Oradan çıkınca sola doğru dönüp devam edeceğiz",
              "loc_lat": "41.0710419",
              "loc_lng": "29.0127192"
            }]
          },
          "3": {
            "wtype_id": "3",
            "wtype_name": "Eczane",
            "wtype_icon": "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
            "locations": [{
              "loc_id": "14",
              "loc_type": "3",
              "loc_name": "a",
              "loc_number": "b",
              "loc_pazartesi": "0",
              "loc_sali": "0",
              "loc_carsamba": "0",
              "loc_persembe": "0",
              "loc_cuma": "1",
              "loc_cumartesi": "0",
              "loc_pazar": "0",
              "loc_open": "800",
              "loc_close": "1200",
              "loc_city": "41",
              "loc_subcity": "505",
              "loc_adress": "asd",
              "loc_tarif": "asda",
              "loc_lat": "40.5880381636505",
              "loc_lng": "30.481870596093742"
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

jQuery.each(props, function(key, value) {
  $.each(value.sub_citys, function(key2, value2) {
    $.each(value2.wtype, function(key3, value3) {
      $.each(value3.locations, function(key4, value4) {
        var Location = {
          coords: {
            lat: parseFloat(value4.loc_lat),
            lng: parseFloat(value4.loc_lng)
          },
          iconImage: value3.wtype_icon,
          content: '<div style="text-align:center;"><h5>' + value4.loc_name + '</h5><a>' + value4.loc_adress + '</a><br/><small>' + value4.loc_tarif + '</small><hr/>'
        }
        console.log(Location)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since your function was not complete, I opted to just log the `Location` object for now.

What I'm not sure to answer yet, is that „my Array” contains more elements than „my Object” (a.k.a. `props`). Shall the values be `null`? Stay as is?